# Where clause with calculated column

Tags: sql

Hello i want to add a condition here like `where Date between ..` and `SalesPercentage > 50` but it salespercentage is not a column in db and its just casted like in the code below.

How can i use it. Thanks in advance.

```
      var sql = @"SELECT TOP 10 
                    sp.ProductName, 
                    SUM(sp.QtySold) AS QtySold,
                    SUM(r.QtyinPieces) AS StockLimit,                  
                    CAST(    (CAST    (SUM(sp.QtySold) AS FLOAT)     /    CAST(SUM(r.QtyinPieces) AS FLOAT)  ) * 100 AS DECIMAL(8,2)       ) [SalesPercentage]
                FROM 
                    Sales_productholder sp
                    JOIN Orders_productholder r ON (sp.ProductID = r.ProductID)

                GROUP BY 
                    sp.ProductName, r.ProductID, r.QtyinPieces
                ORDER BY 
                    SUM(sp.QtySold) DESC";
```

Update: I have combobox that have items like 5,10,20 and i want to use it as parameters for `Top 5`. But it always result in error `Incorrect syntax near TOP`

Here is what i tried:

SELECT TOP @Top

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Top", cboTop.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

and

```
string topp = cboTop.SelectedItem.ToString();
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Top", topp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `HAVING` like this.

```
HAVING
    CAST( (CAST ( SUM(sp.QtySold) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(r.QtyinPieces) AS FLOAT) ) * 100 AS DECIMAL(8,2) ) > 50
```

All query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    sp.ProductName, 
    SUM(sp.QtySold) AS QtySold,
    SUM(r.QtyinPieces) AS StockLimit,                  
    CAST( (CAST ( SUM(sp.QtySold) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(r.QtyinPieces) AS FLOAT) ) * 100 AS DECIMAL(8,2) ) [SalesPercentage]
FROM 
    Sales_productholder sp
    JOIN Orders_productholder r ON (sp.ProductID = r.ProductID)
WHERE [Date] between @DateBegin and @DateAdd
GROUP BY 
    sp.ProductName, r.ProductID, r.QtyinPieces
HAVING
    CAST( (CAST ( SUM(sp.QtySold) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(r.QtyinPieces) AS FLOAT) ) * 100 AS DECIMAL(8,2) ) > 50
ORDER BY 
    SUM(sp.QtySold) DESC
```

Comment: Are you still there sir? i want to add a question.

Comment: Yes, I am here, what is the question?

Comment: write like this  `SELECT TOP (@Top)`

Comment: Thank you so much again sir. i have converted the item to int first and it worked with (@top). Thank you!